# Is it safe to call BeginRecieve() in a while loop whose condition looks at connected Sockets Status?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, network-programming, threadpool

I am writing a TCP/IP Client to send and receive data simultaneously to a connected host. My approach is to connect to the endpoint and use the Socket.Connected property to loop between receiving and sending if there is any data to send. All methods are async with blocking in place for reading data from the stream. Is there anything wrong with calling BeginReceieve multiple times in a loop? Seeing at this runs via the thread-pool does the underlying runtime manage the number of threads spooled for each call or should I be looking to control when I call begin receive within the said while loop?

Comment: I think it save to call BeginRecive() in loop.

I dont Know why you want while loop Because BeginRevice() need a callback Method and whenever client/server send update it automatically call the callback method with the results

Comment: Hi @Tyson 
I loop to allow me continue receiving while the socket is connected. and further after a configured wait I can lookup data to send. This essentially will be repeated for as long as the connection is good.
Is your thought-line that the BeginRecieve() threads will be closed by the ThreadPool after some time of not actually getting any data from the connected host?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop when you call BeginRecive(). BeginRecive() is async method and when you write _socket.BeginRecive() it Begins to asynchronously receive data from a connected Socket/Client.

For Example:

```
    public static void SetupRegisterServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up the Messesing Server!");
        _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 102));
        _serverSocket.Listen(5); //Backlog is pending conditions can exists.    
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null); //Async method BeginAccept if any client connect it will call the AcceptCallback method 
        Console.WriteLine("Messesing Server running......");
    }
```

AcceptCallback function

```
    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);//End accept 
        Console.WriteLine("Client Connect To Messesings Server");
        _clientSocketList.Add(socket);// add client to list 
         // Start reciving from the connected client with callback function ReciveCallback
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReciveCallback), socket); 
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null); //Here we again accepting clients.
    }
```

Recive callback method

```
    private static void ReciveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
            //here you will get the socket of the clint which send the data
            Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int recived = socket.EndReceive(ar);//recive == data.length
            byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[recived];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuffer, recived);
            //Data send from client
            string decodedText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuffer);
            //Start receiving again from the same client 
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReciveCallback), socket);
    }
```

You can also use socket.BeginSend() to send data in receive callback

Comment: Thanks for the well illustrated answer @Tyson .
In my scenario I am building a client so in place of listen I define the socket and call BeginConnect.
Assuming my connection is successful I can essentially just call BeginRecieve() as per your ReadCall back method however assuming these methods are called in a main method, will execution not end as soon as we reach the last line in the said method which would effectively terminate Receive until the service/app is started?